# Is it possible to use pointer to pointer to char (char **pptr_char) to store dynamic number of dynamic size strings?

Tags: c, memory, pointers

Variable `char **pptr_char` starts as being `NULL`. But then as the program proceeds we take string input from the user. Each string is stored in `**pptr_char` and thus there is need to dynamically allocate memory in the X- and as well Y- dimension.
Is this possible in C?

Since all the strings will not have the same length how will the pointer arithmetic work out i.e doing `*ptr_char+1` to goto the next string?

Any idea how it shall be done?

Comment: You've got two options: allocate one large block and place the strings consecutively in that block;  or allocate a separate piece of memory for each string. In both cases you have a list of `char *`s .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. And you would use `ptr_char + i` to move to the `i`th string.  It doesn't matter that the strings are not the same length.  It only matters that the **pointers** are the same length, which of course they are.

```
                Points to memory location      Memory location contains
ptr_char            X                        a pointer to string1 (string could live anywhere)
ptr_char + 1        X+4 (or 8 for 64-bit)    a pointer to string2 (string could live anywhere)
ptr_char + 2        X+8 (or 16)              a pointer to string3 (string could live anywhere)
```

So you first allocate a block of memory to hold the N `char*` (that block starts a memory location `X` (though of course the `X` is whatever the operating system picks for you -- you have no control).

Then you allocate memory for the `i`th string and set the `i`th `char*` to point to that memory.

Answer (score 0):

`char **pptr_char` is an array of strings (char pointers). `pptr_char[0]` is the first pointer, `pptr_char[1]` is the second pointer and so on and it does not matter what is pointed by these pointers. If you want to store strings in a continuous memory region, you can do:

```
pptr_char    = (char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char*)); // say we have 20 strings max
pptr_char[0] = (char*) malloc(large chunk size)
strcpy(pptr_char[0], "string0");
pptr_char[1] = pptr_char[0] + strlen(pptr_char[0]+1);
strcpy(pptr_char[1], "string1");
pptr_char[2] = pptr_char[1] + strlen(pptr_char[1]+1);
....
```